# django/python: pass **kwargs

Tags: python, django

I want to build a url. My function adds the word `kwargs` to the result, which it should not.

```
custom_redirect('mieteinheit', kwargs={"wohnungsgruppenname": form.cleaned_data["wohnungsgruppenname"]})

def custom_redirect(url_name, *args, **kwargs):
    #some code is passed
    "?%s" % urllib.parse.urlencode(kwargs)
```

This creates:

```
?kwargs=%7B%27wohnungsgruppenname%27%3A+%27ghs%27%7D
```

But it should create

```
?wohnungsgruppenname%3Dwohnungsgruppenname
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missunderstood how keyword arguments are used.

Instead of calling your function like you do, try this instead:

```
custom_redirect(
    'mieteinheit', 
    wohnungsgruppenname=form.cleaned_data["wohnungsgruppenname"])
```

This way, the word 'wohnungsgruppenname' will become a key in the dict `kwargs`. The way you did it, it creates a nested dict, which is not what you nedd.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769475/9225671) for a better explanation of how `kwargs` works.